# MySQL Stored Procedures returns only the first row for Select Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have multiple stored procedures in my MySQL database. I am using phpMyAdmin to help in the administration of the database. My stored procedures have this weird behavior, if I go to the routines tab in phpMyAdmin and click execute I will only get one row returned. If I go to the SQL tab and type in `CALL Emp6();` It works exactly as designed. Here is the stored procedure code below

```
SELECT CONCAT( Employee.Emp_FirstName, " ", Employee.Emp_LastName ) AS 'Sales Rep',     CONCAT( '$', FORMAT( SUM( Cars.Price ) , 2 ) ) AS 'Value of Cars Sold'

FROM Cars, Employee, Purchase

WHERE Purchase.Car_ID = Cars.Car_ID

AND Purchase.Emp_ID = Employee.Emp_ID

GROUP BY Employee.Emp_LastName
```

This SQL code also works when placed in the "SQL" query window in phpMyAdmin and run.

Answer (score 0):

With phpMyAdmin 4.1.0, I cannot reproduce your problem. A stored procedure containing only a SELECT statement returns all rows.

Possible sources of your problem: if you are not using the mysqli extension in phpMyAdmin, or if your MySQL client library is not the same version than your MySQL server (this should not happen if you're using the excellent mysqlnd native driver).